# Understanding SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter behaviour

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-aws, spring-integration-aws

I'm trying to understand the behavior of `SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` to address memory issue. 
The upstream system dumps thousands of messages in `aws-sqs-queue`, all of the messages are received immediately by `SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. On the AWS console I do not see any messages available on the queue.
The `SqsMessageProcesser` then processes 1 message every 5 seconds.

Here's the log:

> 2019-05-21 17:28:18 INFO  SQSMessageProcessor:88 - --- inside
>   sqsMessageProcesser--- 2019-05-21 17:28:23 INFO 
>   SQSMessageProcessor:88 - --- inside sqsMessageProcesser--- 2019-05-21
>   17:28:28 INFO  SQSMessageProcessor:88 - --- inside
>   sqsMessageProcesser--- 2019-05-21 17:28:33 INFO 
>   SQSMessageProcessor:88 - --- inside sqsMessageProcesser--- 2019-05-21
>   17:28:38 INFO  SQSMessageProcessor:88 - --- inside
>   sqsMessageProcesser--- .........................

Does this mean that while `SqsMessageProcesser` is processing 1 message every 5 seconds, thousands of messages are being held in (server) memory of the `in-channel`?

Each db transaction takes around 5 seconds and currently we are facing 'outofmemory' issues on PRD.

Will it help if i set the capacity on the `QueueChannel` and `setMaxNumberOfMessages` for `SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`? 
If yes, is there a standard way to calculate these values?

```java
  @Bean(name = "in-channel")
  public PollableChannel sqsInputChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel();
  }

  @Autowired
  private AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs;

  @Bean
  public MessageProducer sqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapterForItems() {

    SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
        new SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(amazonSqs, "aws-sqs-queue");
    adapter.setOutputChannelName("in-channel");
    return adapter;
  }

  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "in-channel",
      poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "5000" , maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
  public void sqsMessageProcesser(Message<?> receive) throws ProcesserException {
  logger.info("--- inside sqsMessageProcesser---")
  // db transactions.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is an anti-pattern to place a `QueueChannel` for message-driven channel adapter. The later is already async and based on some task scheduling. So, shifting consumed messages from source into an in-memory queue is definitely leading into some troubles.

You should consider to have a direct channel instead and let SQS consuming thread to be blocked until your `sqsMessageProcesser` finishes its job. This way you will guarantee no data loss.